# Why is my gridview header shrinking when I position fixed it?

Tags: css, asp.net, gridview

Source : https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/614041/GridView-with-Fixed-Header-and-Scroll-Bar

I have create a CSS class for fixing my header inside a bootstrap panel.

**CSS**

```
.FixedHeader {
   position: absolute;
   font-weight: bold;
   background-color:aquamarine;
}
```

**ASP.NET GridView**

```
<div class="panel-body" style="overflow-y:scroll;">
<asp:GridView ID="myGridView" runat="server" Width="560px" 
                                class="table table-hover table-bordered" 

                                align="center" HeaderStyle-Wrap="true" 
                                HeaderStyle-CssClass="FixedHeader"
                                >
```

The result is pretty funny. It's better explained by the image below.

[image]

You can see the three column headers on the left... The size of the header columns shrinks...

**UPDATE**

Below is the result when I put `width:100%` in the header css class

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Please try to add with 100%for the header.

Comment: I did. I thought it would take 100% of asp:gridview but it goes accross the boostrap panel to the right...No a good idea...See the new image above